# Using clmm() for ordinal dependent variables

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, ordinal-data

I have a 2 (Complexity: 1=Simple vs. 2=Complex) by 3 (Type: 1=A vs. 2=B vs. 3=C) design, where each participant completed separate tasks counterbalanced across the 6 conditions, and then gave a rating on a 4-Likert scale (1, 2, 3, 4).

I am trying to run mixed models for the ordinal dependent variable *rating* with the `ordinal` package in R using `clmm()`, and including the participant and the item as random effects. It's the first time I run this type of analyses, and I would like to understand better if what I'm doing is correct, and how to interpret the outcome of the model.

Here is an extract of my data:

```
    'data.frame':   550 obs. of  13 variables:
     $ Set         : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Complexity  : Factor w/ 2 levels "1Simple","2Complex": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
     $ Type        : Factor w/ 3 levels "1A","2B",..: 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ correct     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`
     $ report      : Factor w/ 2 levels "NoReport","YesReport": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
     $ rating      : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "1"<"2"<"3"<"4": 3 4 4 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 ...
     $ pp          : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ condition   : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
     $ stim        : Factor w/ 19 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 15 17 19 1 3 4 8 10 13 15 ...
```

I have run the model:

```
model3 = clmm(rating ~ Complexity*Type+ (1 + Complexity*Type|pp) + (1 + Complexity+ Type|stim), data = datafile3, Hess = TRUE)
summary(model3)
```

which seems to converge. The results are the following:

```
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: rating ~ Complexity *Type + (1 + Complexity* Type| pp) +      (1 + Complexity+ Type| stim)
data:    datafile3

 link  threshold nobs logLik  AIC     niter       max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  550  -656.71 1391.41 5927(29971) 4.22e-04 3.2e+02

Random effects:
 Groups Name                       Variance Std.Dev. Corr                               
 pp     (Intercept)                3.173916 1.78155                                     
        Complexity2Complex         1.588748 1.26046  -0.391                             
        Type2B                     0.380579 0.61691   0.227 -0.234                      
        Type3C                     3.534773 1.88010  -0.533  0.328 -0.342               
        Complexity2Complex:Type2B  1.723185 1.31270   0.137 -0.453 -0.428  0.349        
        Complexity2Complex:Type3C  4.512270 2.12421   0.477 -0.847  0.646 -0.633 -0.011 
 stim   (Intercept)                0.011854 0.10887                                     
        Complexity2Complex         0.008937 0.09454   1.000                             
        Type2B                     0.011972 0.10942  -1.000 -1.000                      
        Type3C                     0.040845 0.20210  -1.000 -1.000  1.000               
Number of groups:  pp 24,  stim 19 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
Complexity2Complex         -0.4679     0.4209  -1.112   0.2662  
Type2B                     -0.5237     0.3132  -1.672   0.0945 .
Type3C                     -0.6372     0.5058  -1.260   0.2077  
Complexity2Complex:Type2B   0.5966     0.5301   1.125   0.2604  
Complexity2Complex:Type3C   0.3679     0.6783   0.542   0.5876  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -2.7290     0.4475  -6.098
2|3  -1.0572     0.4310  -2.453
3|4   0.5686     0.4288   1.326
```

I can see that the correlations for the random effect of stimuli (items) is high, and I wonder if I need to simplify the model because of this?

Second, I am not sure how to interpret the coefficients.
Should I interpret the coefficients of the `summary(model3)`, or should I run `RVAideMemoire::Anova.clmm(model3,type="II")` and interpret those?

Finally, if there is any significant main effect or interaction, I was thinking to run:

`summary(emmeans(model3,pairwise~Complexity|Type,adjust="tukey",mode="linear.predictor",type="rating"))`

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: On the `emmeans` part, I suggest omitting the `mode` and `type` arguments. The default is on a latent-variable scale and what you specified gives a prediction for every single level. Also your `type` is invalid. See `vignette("sophisticated")` for a fairly detailed example with a `clm` model